# Develop API from wordpress site to fetch data from Android App?

Tags: php, android, wordpress

Actually, I don't know Php. But I have to create api from wordpress site so that I can fetch data from the site in the android app so that it can help to connect my application to the site.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Question is that how to develop API from wordpress site to be used in android.?

Comment: I think her question is how to devevlop APIs for wordpress? These are the APIs going to be consumed for mobile apps.

Comment: yes,,u r right.. @PareshMayani

Comment: Start by learning one of the many server side languages. There are many resources available on the internet for that. Apart from that, your question is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use follwoing plugins :

1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/
2. http://www.parorrey.com/solutions/json-api-auth/
3. http://www.parorrey.com/solutions/json-api-user/

I used above plugins to create endpoints for an android app.